# Acceptable CFI but poor TLI

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I'm working on a path analysis using lavaan in R. Here is my model fit result:
Chi square: >.05
Confirmatory Fit Index (CFI): 0.94
Tucker Lewis Index (TLI): 0.86
Root Mean Square Error of Approximation (RMSEA): 0.05
(Standardized)Root Mean Square Residual (SRMR) 0.05

I'm wondering what is the reason for the poor TLI?
I know that if CFI is less than 1, TLI will always be smaller than CFI. But what explains the huge difference between them?
I have a relatively small sample size: 187. Would it be related to that? 
Please advise how I should interpret this result and whether I can still consider this model to have acceptable fit. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms, particularly CFI and TLI.

Comment: Thanks, is it clear enough now?

Comment: Please add more detail, to include the observed correlations and the type of each variable.